# Why is a variable frequency drive (VFD) always powered from a phase shift transformer?

Tags: transformer

I have seen that VFDs of rating 350kW and above are generally powered from a phase shift transformer. Even when the load is considerably high, why can't we use an ordinary transformer instead of a phase shift transformer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harmonics & multi-pulse rectifiers.

Industry is charged in VA (not Watts) and equally have some very harsh requirements on the harmonics they create.

A simple 6pulse rectifier will produce harmonics at 5,7,11,13...

A relatively economical method to reduce this is to goto a multipulse rectifier arrangement which can be achieved with phase shifting transformers

Star --> Star:Delta  and two 6pulse rectifiers will produce a 12pulse setup with harmonics at 11,13,23,25....

Comment: Then in that case the phase shift transformer should be connected at the point of common coupling if the sole purpose is only to mitigate the harmonics. It could be nice if you elaborate the answer and explain it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be at the PCC. That would be bad as you could have a significant distance to the point of loading

Comment: I am not getting your point. Can u please elaborate it

Comment: The point of common coupling is the point where different customers are connected. This is very very rarely the point of consumption.

Comment: Then in that case cant we use a zig zag transformer instead of a phase shift transformer ?

Comment: You can but autotransformers do not provide as good harmonic results and equally do not provide isolation

Comment: I am asking about zig zag transformer only. I know that auto transformer wont serve the purpose. Please clarify

Comment: You could as that is just winding specifics for a star:star-delta to produce the needed phase shift